# How to handle JSON array response while using APIConsumer?

Tags: chainlink

Using the APIConsumer contract we can feed data from API to the smart contract.

Eg: If the server response is:

```py
  {
   "RAW":{"ETH":{"USD":{"VOLUME24HOUR": 10000,}}}
  }
```

Then, data can be obtained as:

```py
request.add("get", URL);
request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
```

Similarly, If the server response contains some JSON array,
Eg:

```py
{
"date":"530934083405834",
"results": [
  {
    "id": 9865,
    "rank":1
  },
  {
   "id": 9869,
   "rank": 2
  },
  {
   "id": 9866,
   "rank": 3
  }
]}
```

Then in this case is there a way to get the **id** of the **rank 1** i.e `results[0]["id"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `results[0]["id"]` your path in the request needs to be

```js
request.add("path", "results.0.id");
```