# Convert a JSON array into a solidity mapping in a chainlink node external adapter?

Tags: json, solidity, chainlink

I have a custom external adapter runnning on a chainlink node. When the adapter is triggered, it gets a response from an api that sends back a json object with a list of objects. I want to covert the array in this json object into a solidity mapping for my smart contract.

For example could I get the property "array of objects" from this response and convert it into a solidity mapping for my client contract to use?

````
    "random": 89,
    "random float": 10.669,
    "bool": true,
    "date": "1980-11-24",
    "regEx": "helloooooooooooooooooooooo to you",
    "enum": "json",
    "firstname": "Stevana",
    "lastname": "Killigrew",
    "city": "Port Moresby",
    "country": "Isle of Man",
    "countryCode": "PY",
    "email uses current data": "Stevana.Killigrew@gmail.com",
    "email from expression": "Stevana.Killigrew@yopmail.com",
    "array": [
        "Vanessa",
        "Chloris",
        "Glynnis",
        "Fidelia",
        "Kaja"
    ],
    "array of objects": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "index start at 5": 5,
            "team": "na",
            "company": "CVS",
            "department": "hair and beauty"
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "index start at 5": 6,
            "team": "na",
            "company": "CVS",
            "department": "hair and beauty"
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "index start at 5": 7,
            "team": "na",
            "company": "CVS",
            "department": "hair and beauty"
        }
    ],
    "Ronna": {
        "age": 82
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

One can't get an "array of objects" at the moment from the external adapter, here is [the list of currently supported response types](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/#response-types).

You will need to make a [Multi-Varibale Responses](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/) request and then get each individual property [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032165/how-to-handle-json-array-response-while-using-apiconsumer)