# How to receive an int array using a Chainlink oracle?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm traing to get data from an off-chain API to use it in my smart contract. For this, I'm using Chainlink oracle.

I've seen jobs to get one Uint256 or one Bool or a Bytes32 variable. But what if you want to receive an array?
I want to receive something like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as an `uint[]` to be able to loop and use the individual values.

What's the best way to do this?

I already used the Get->Bytes32 and the Get->Bytes, method but then I need to parse these bytes inside the EVM and I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please add more details like: which method you are calling from Chainlink oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly retrieve an array response from a Chainlink Oracle.

If you'd like to run your own Chainlink oracle / node, you'll need to ensure you have the latest oracle contract deployed (`Operator.sol` as of this post), which supports the broadest array of data types: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/fulfilling-requests#setup-your-operator-contract

The Chainlink job configuration for returning a uint256[] object should look something like this (showing an excerpt of the `ethabiencode` job task only. please note that the input `${parse}` to this job task is necessarily the output from a `jsonparse` job task, which should be an array (ie, `[10,20]`)):

```
    ...
    encode_data [
                type="ethabiencode" 
                abi="(bytes32 requestId, uint256[] value)" 
                data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"value\\": $(parse)}"
                ]
    ...
```

And finally, the fulfill function of your consumer contract (ie, the function that receives the result on-chain) will look something like this:

```
    // Receive the result from the LinkWellNodes.io Chainlink oracle
    uint256[] public responseArr;
    event RequestFulfilled(bytes32 indexed requestId);
    function fulfill(bytes32 requestId, uint256[] memory data) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId) {
        responseArr = data;     // example value: responseArr[0] = 10, responseArr[1] = 20
    }
```

If you just want to retrieve this data without running your own Chainlink oracle, you can ask an existing node operator to support your request.

The following link is an example of how to retrieve a uint256 array on Ethereum Goerli testnet from an existing oracle provider (disclaimer: I am a member of this Oracle team): https://docs.linkwellnodes.io/services/direct-request-jobs/testnets/Ethereum-Goerli-Testnet-Jobs?dataType=Uint256%5B%5D

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment arrays are not supported as a response type, here is [the list of currently supported response types](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/#response-types).

You can:

1. Read `uint256` value by `uint256` value, assuming it's a fixed-size array, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032165/how-to-handle-json-array-response-while-using-apiconsumer/)
2. Make a [Multi-Varibale Responses](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/) request
3. Make a [Large Responses](https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/) request, which you mentioned, and handle those `bytes32` values. Keep in mind that, currently, any return value must fit within 32 bytes. If the value is bigger than that, make multiple requests.

Comment: In your option 1, you cannot add multiple "path" paremeters to the same request, right? Like this: request.add("path", "results.0.id"); 
request.add("path", "results.1.id"); 
request.add("path", "results.2.id"); 
request.add("path", "results.3.id");

Comment: Option 1 is more for reading elements of the array one by one. If you are looking for additional methods for building a Chainlink Request, they are listed here https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-framework/#methods-2